# Object access issue in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am passing array of object in json and trying to access it in foreach loop but I got an error **"Trying to get property of non-object"**

**JSON**

> {"i":[{"name":"Siddhesh
>   mishra","mobile":"7798645895","gender":"M"},{"name":"Pratik
>   pande","mobile":"7798645891","gender":"M"}]

**foreach loop**

```
foreach ($request->i as $key => $insrtobj) {
 if($insrtobj->name && $insrtobj->mobile && $insrtobj->gender){
 }
 else
     $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1, 'success'=>0,     'error_msg'=>'request with mandatory param','message'=>'check the input data']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel Request object automatically decodes json input using `json_decode`, but it passes `true` as the second parameter to convert objects to arrays. So, when accessing the json data from the request, you need to treat it as an associative array, not an object.

```
if ($insrtobj['name'] && $insrtobj['mobile'] && $insrtobj['gender']) {
```

Comment: Thank you @patricus . I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert you JSON data into array form and use it...:

```
$arrData = json_decode(YOURJSONDATA, true);
foreach ($arrData as $key => $insrtData) {
 //your rest of code...
}
```

NOTE: When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. [Docs](http://php.net/json_decode)